# How Facebook App integrate with Siri. Any Apple Framework to do that?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, siri

I have an task to make ours company application more voice controlled. To do this I would like to integrate it with Siri the same way like Facebook app integrates (Look at the screens). How can I accomplish this. I was looking for some frameworks on Apple side that can let me do it but I can't find any suitable framework to do it. I know this must be something like **service extension** or **app extension** that is starting with iOS (not with my application) because Siri knows that the Facebook is integrating with it even when the Facebook app is turned off. Take a look at those screens to see what kind of integration I'm talking about. This screens can be opened when I say to Siri: "What can You do":

[image: List of application that integrate with Siri]

[image: Commands that Facebook app recognize]

Comment: The Siri extension API supports a very specific set of tasks (such as messaging). It cannot be used for arbitrary voice control in an app. (And the Facebook stuff is probably built-in by Apple themselves, not provided by an extension).

Comment: So how developers of the Facebook app, Photos app did that?

Comment: They didn't. Apple did it for them as part of iOS. This opens up a bit in iOS 10, but again, just for very specific tasks.

Comment: Are You sure? Now I'm starting to wonder if this is possible in iOS 9 because on the Siri app list theres is a Twitter app too but I haven't installed this app yet. Also there are almost all build in apps on this list that is coming with iOS so maybe You're right. I'll try to remove Facebook app to see if the Facebook disappears from this list.

Comment: Because you're not seem to be convinced, I confirm that @Thilo is right !

Comment: @Thilo - Thanks For Your reply. When You mention about iOS 10 did You mean SiriKit?

Comment: @Thilo and Anthonin C. - Thank You both for Your time and comments. It seems that I have to wait for iOS 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment mentioned, Apple decided to partner with certain companies and integrate these features into the OS and it's impossible for you to do so yourself. If you go to the Settings menu, you'll notice you can link your Facebook/Twitter/Flickr/Vimeo account even if you don't have the corresponding apps installed.